# Does build createIndex() a new index over the whole collection?

Tags: mongodb

What happens when I add a new document to my collection and run the createIndex() function. Does MongoDB build a new index over the whole collection (time and resource consuming)? Or is MongoDB just updating the index for the single document (time and resource saving)? I am not sure because I found this in the documentation (3.0):

> By default, MongoDB builds indexes in the foreground, which prevents all read and write operations to the database while the index builds. Also, no operation that requires a read or write lock on all databases (e.g. listDatabases) can occur during a foreground index build.

I am asking because I need a dynamic 2dsphere index which will be updated continuous. If it needs to build the index everytime over the whole collection it would take too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building an index indexes all existing documents and also cause all future documents to get indexed as well. So if you `insert` new documents into an already indexed collection (or `update` the indexed fields of existing documents), the indexes will get updated.

When you call `createIndex` and an index of the same type over the same fields already exists, nothing happens.